# Heroku Hobby tier allows up to "10" process types but not allowed to scale horizontally?

Tags: heroku

In the detailed comparison chart, its says max number of process type is 10 (could have 10 dynos). It also says that hobby tier is not allowed horizontal scaling (meaning only 1 web dyno, no more web or worker dynos). From what I understand horizontal scaling means adding more web or/and worker processes.

It seems contradictory to me. I tried to go through its documentation, but still don't understand.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Web Apps just serve webpages or API from the `web` process type.

Advanced Web Apps may have extra features, for e.g. a `worker` process (say, you've to send 1000 emails, so you put that task in a task queue, and the worker process handles it. So your main `web` process can respond quickly to the user), a `scheduler` process (to do cron stuff) etc.

In hobby tier on Heroku you can have 10 of these workers, however your main `web` process (which handles the webpages/API calls) will still be handled by a single, basic, dyno. A dyno is akin to 1 core of a processor (hardware). Now if you've a lot of load/visitors on your website, this might not be enough; you might want 4 dynos to be handling your `web` process alone. Well, that you can't do on the hobby tier.

Comment: OK, so if I understand you clearly, this is what the doc means.
1) Hobby tier allows only 1 web proce.
2) 10 in the doc refers to worker processes only.
3) Horizontal scaling restriction only apply to web process.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Ten refers to 1 `web` + upto 9 `worker` processes 3) Horizontal scaling restriction on Hobby tier applies to each of the 10 process types individually (i.e. suppose you've to send 10Mn mails, then again one single hobby tier worker might not be able to do it. You'll either have to distribute it over a workers, or upgrade your Heroku plan so that a single worker can 'scale' over multiple dynos).